# How does pylint use easy_install at runtime?

Tags: python, easy-install, pylint, tox

**Sorry this is a long question. See the sentence in bold at the bottom for the TL;DR version.**

I've spent many hours trying to track down a problem where pylint sometimes doesn't report all the errors in a module. Note that it does find some errors (e.g. long lines), just not all of them (e.g. missing docstrings).

I'm running pylint 1.7.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. (The version available from apt was 1.5.2 but installing via pip gives 1.7.2.)

We typically run pylint from tox, with a `tox.ini` that looks something like this (this is a cut-down version):

```
[tox]
envlist = py35
[testenv]
setenv =
    MODULE_NAME=our_module
ignore_errors = True
deps =
    -r../requirements.txt
whitelist_externals = bash
commands =
    pip install --editable=file:///{toxinidir}/../our_other_module
    pip install -e .
    bash -c \'set -o pipefail; pylint --rcfile=../linting/pylint.cfg our_module | tee pylint.log\'
```

Amongst other things, the `../requirements.txt` file contains a line for `pylint==1.7.2`.

The behaviour is like this:

- [wrong] When the line that imports `our_other_module` is present, pylint appears to complete successfully and not report any warnings, even though there are errors in the `our_module` code that it should pick up.
- [correct] When that line is commented out, pylint generates the expected warnings.

As part of tracking this down I took two copies of the `.tox` folder with and without the module import, naming them `.tox-no-errors-reported` and `.tox-with-errors-reported` respectively.

So now, even without sourcing their respective tox virtualenvs, I can do the following:

- `$ .tox-no-errors-reported/py35/bin/pylint --rcfile=../linting/pylint.cfg our_module` -- reports no linting warnings
- `$ .tox-with-errors-reported/py35/bin/pylint --rcfile=../linting/pylint.cfg our_module` -- reports the expected linting warnings

(where I just changed the `pylint` script's `#!` line in each case to reference the `python3.5` inside that specific .tox directory instead of the unrenamed `.tox`)

By diffing `.tox-no-errors-reported` and `.tox-with-errors-reported`, I've found that they are very similar. But I can make the "no errors" version start to report errors by removing the path to `our_other_module` from `.tox-no-errors-reported/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth`.

So my question is **why is pylint using easy_install at runtime, and what is it picking up from our other component that is causing it to fail to report some errors**.

As I understand it, pylint has dependencies on `astroid` and `logilab-common`, but including these in the `requirements.txt` doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for the surprising `pylint` behavior is the `--editable` option.

> it creates a special .egg-link file in the deployment directory, that links to your project’s source code. And, ..., it will also update the easy-install.pth file to include your project’s source code

The `pth` file will then affect the `sys.path` which affects the [module import logic](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/blob/03f3ea786885d794d3cdeaa82df4ce36d60d68e1/astroid/interpreter/_import/spec.py#L251) of `astroid` and it is deeply buried in the call stack of [pylint.expand_files](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/5cb00c2ce4b7a9f75d4e9e86601f0a9df7bf673b/pylint/lint.py#L881) via `pylint.utils.expand_modules`. Also `pylint` identifies the module part and function names in the AST using `astroid.modutils.get_module_part`.

To test the theory, you can try calling some of the affected astroid functions manually:

```
import sys, astroid
print(sys.path)
print(astroid.modutils.get_module_part('your_package.sub_package.module'))
astroid.modutils.file_from_modpath(['your_package', 'sub_package', 'module'])
```